# Modifico una variable auxiliar, igualo la auxiliar a

Tags: python, variables, datos, guardar

En Python, leo 1 archivo, y guardo los datos en 2 variables distintas, el problema es que cuando modifico la segunda, y luego igualo la segunda a la primera para que no haya cambios, también se modifica la primera.
matriz es una clase

```
Matrices = matriz()
Matrices_Mod = matriz()
```

Modifico esta: `Matrices_Mod`, y luego realizo la igualación:

```
Matrices_Mod = Matrices
```

Pero `Matrices` es la que se modifica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Python, como en otros lenguajes, las estructuras de datos (listas, tuplas, diccionarios) son asignadas a las variables por referencia y no por valor.

Particularmente en Python, si una variable que tiene una estructura de datos se asigna a otra, esta última no creará una estructura nueva, si no que apuntará a la misma dirección de memoria que tiene la primera. Entonces lo que se haga en una, se verá reflejado en la otra inmediatamente. Veámoslo con ejemplos:

```
>>> # ### ASIGNACION POR VALOR
>>> a = 20
>>> b = a
>>> print(a, b)
20, 20
>>> b = 50
>>> print(a, b)
20 50 # <-- Comportamiento esperado
>>>
>>>
>>> # ### ASIGNACION POR REFERENCIA
>>> c = [2, 3, 5]
>>> d = c
>>> print(c, d)
[2, 3, 5] [2, 3, 5]
>>> d.append(7) # Agregar un item más a d
>>> print(c, d)
[2, 3, 5, 7] [2, 3, 5, 7] # <-- ¿Qué?
```

Para asignar una copia de la estructura de datos a otra variable, básicamente hay dos formas:

```
>>> d = c.copy() # <-- Método recomendado
>>> e = c[:] # Otra forma, no tan recomendada, pero es usual
>>>
>>>
>>> d.append(11)
>>> e.append(13)
>>> print(c, d, e)
[2, 3, 5, 7] [2, 3, 5, 7, 11] [2, 3, 5, 7, 13] # <-- Comportamiento deseado
```

Ambas formas generan una copia en direcciones de memoria distintas de la original, por lo que podrán ser modificadas sin alterar la lista madre.

Answer (score -1):

Al momento de guardar en las 2 variables , lo que estas guardando internamente son las direcciones de memoria, por tanto cuando modificas uno el otro tambien sera modificado, intenta crear una copia identica y no igualando, puedes cerar un metodo que copie el objeto. saludos

Comment: Gracias, al final no entendí muy bien como hacerlo, ya que estoy usando objetos, me iba a tardar demasiado y no lo abría entendido.
Al final lo que hice fue utilizar la libreria de copy para utiilzar copy.deepcopy.
Esto puede funcionar en python, pero con todos los lenguajes es asi?, solo cambia de apuntador?

Comment: Deberias ilustrar el problema, no simplemente hablar sobre él. Falta código que demuestre lo que planteas.